# Error installing postgres on Windows 8

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am using a Windows 8 laptop as my dev server.

I am trying to install postgres on my laptop, but I get the following error:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initilization failed.

Here is a video of my efforts (excuse the terrible quality, I haven't used screen capture software before today):

```
http://youtu.be/LwhqCXiji8E
```

Installation file:

```
fixing permissions on existing directory C:/postgres/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
10
selecting default shared_buffers ... The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
400kB
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in C:/postgres/data/base/1 ... The system cannot find the path specified.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "C:/postgres/data"

Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Script stderr:
 Program ended with an error exit code

Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\postgres/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\postgres" "C:\postgres\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0 : Program ended with an error exit code
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 The database cluster initialisation failed.
```

Comment: I'd say it's not off topic as the dev will mirror my prod, so it needs to function. Secondly, yes. The error message is quite clear, and I'm sure someone has seen this before.

Comment: No, it will not mirror your production system. It's different hardware and different software as Win8 is not a  server OS and a laptop is not a server.

Comment: Firstly, you don't know my prod system. If I want my prod system to be a windows 8 laptop, that's my business. Maybe it will be something running windows server 2012. Different, but close enough to merit the question. Either way, either propose an answer, or offer a real suggestion as to improve the question.

Comment: `If I want my prod system to be a windows 8 laptop, that's my business.` Fine, if we want to classify running servers on client OSes as off-topic, then that's **our** business.  And we do. So, off-topic.

Comment: Check the install logs...

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation#Collect_the_installer_log_file http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28836/pg-install-the-database-cluster-initialisation-failed From a cursory search on Google it seems there's problems specific to Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://www.windows-commandline.com/add-user-to-group-from-command-line/

```
Solution:
- Uninstall PostgreSQL
- net user postgres /delete
- Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Configure advanced user profile properties -> delete all "Unknown User" instances that seem to be left from postgres
- compmgmt.msc -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> New User... -> User name: postgres, Password: postgrespass -> Create
- compmgmt.msc -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> postgres -> Member of -> Add... -> Administrators -> OK
- copy postgresql-8.4.9-1-windows.exe to C:\
- runas /user:postgres cmd.exe -> cd \ -> postgresql-8.4.9-1-windows.exe -> installed successfully without errors. Checked data folder and confirmed files created successfully.
- compmgmt.msc -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> postgres -> Member of -> Administrators -> Remove
- compmgmt.msc -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> postgres -> Member of -> Add... -> Power Users -> OK
- Installed HM2 -> created db successfully
- Restarted computer -> HM2 runs properly (i.e. just to check postgresql service starts automatically)
```